# Перебор всех control в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Мне в цикле надо перебрать абсолютно все control'ы в форме (в том числе и их дети). С пом. this.controls получаются ток дети именно формы, а мне надо что бы в массиве были все контролы в форме, как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте рекурсию.
Выполнить действие над каждым контролом:

```
public static void ForAllControls(this Control parent, Action<Control> action)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {
        action(c);
        ForAllControls(c, action);
    }
}
```

Получить все контролы указанного типа:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToArray();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl, type))
                          .Concat(controls)
                          .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант использовал, всё заработало