# Проверка нескольких TextBox на пустоту

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

На форме 10-15 `TextBox`'ов, нужно последовательно проверить их на пустоту, как это можно рационально реализовать, чтобы 15 раз не писать

```
if(tb1.Text=="")
{

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте следующее решение для перебора всех `TextBox`: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/565935/177382 (второй вариант).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так перебрать, если все лежит в корне:

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
  //do stuff
}
```

а внутри уже выполнить проверку.

Если на форме есть GroupBox'ы, то нужно подключать рекурсию или стек.

Comment: ну это если все они лежат в корне, и если нужно реально все проверить

Comment: нужно проверять только до первого пустого, а потом вернуть его индекс

Answer (score 1):

Адекватным вариантом, я думаю, будет закинуть все объекты TB в коллекцию и в цикле проверять.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(tb1.Text==""||tb2.Text==""||tb3.Text==""||...)
{
     MessageBox
}
else ...
```

Comment: Необходимо добавить пояснение к тому, что делает ваш код. Код так же должен быть в таком формате, чтобы он компилировался. Ваш код не скомпилируется. Для пояснений в коде можно использовать комментарии `// мой комментарий` в коде. Так же сравнение на пустую строку `Text = ""` не эффективно, гораздо быстрее работает такой вариант `Text?.Length > 0`.